# Re-select option value after AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a pretty simple form I'm building out using PHP, AJAX and jQuery.  The form consists of a select box of the existing people that is populated from the database.  Underneath is common contact information (Address, City, Phone, etc.)  When the page is loaded, the form is empty except for the select box containing the people.

The basic idea is that when the user selects a person, it should populate that person's contact info into the form.  The form appears as a modal window, so I do not want the page to refresh, so I'm sending an AJAX request to the server passing the unique ID and in turn, the server responds with a JSON-encoded PHP array with that person's contact info.  I am taking that information and populating the form.

All of this is working as I need except for the data that should go into select boxes (e.g. State).  I am successfully retrieving the proper state value and have validated that value matches the options in the select, but I cannot get it to change the selected value in the select box.

Here are the highlights of my code:

```
<!-- abridged generated HTML -->
<select name="PersonID" id="PersonID">
    <option value="1">Mike</option>
    <option value="2">Jim</option>
    <!-- etc... -->
</select>

<input type="text" id="City" />

<select name="AttState" class="selectpicker" id="AttState">
    <option>State</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <!--And so on... -->
</select>

<!-- etc...  -->
```

And then the Javascript...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // This will pre-select when the form is initially loaded
    var selState = "TX";

    $("#PersonID").on('change', function(e) {
        personId = $("#PersonID").val();

        $.getJSON('GetPersonInfo.php?q=' + personId, function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                $("#City").val(val.City);
                selState = val(val.State);
                // Plus all of the others...
        });
    });

    $("AttState").val(selState);
});
```

When the form initially loads, the State is getting preselected to Texas; however, when the person is chosen and selState changes (validated by an alert), it doesn't get set to the correct value.  I have read some posts that seem to revolve around ensuring that the JavaScript code living inside of the `$(document).ready(function()` function, so I suspect that the AJAX call doesn't retrigger the function.  I cannot figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should placed this code `$("AttState").val(selState);` inside success callback of AJAX request like so :

```
$.getJSON('GetPersonInfo.php?q=' + personId, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
       $("#City").val(val.City);
       selState = val(val.State);
       // Plus all of the others...

    });
    // its depend on your code whether inside .each() or not
    $("#AttState").val(selState);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback.  I have tried it in there as well, but it doesn't work either.  Note that $("AttState").val(selState); always executes in its current placement.

Comment: Try `console.log(selState)` and see what output you got there. And it would be nice if you can post the rest of the code inside success callback

Comment: There's not any logic in there except for setting the other form elements with their respective values (just repeating the #City logic.  I set the state value last.  console.log(selState) outputs TX as expected.

Comment: Do you console outside success callback, if so, then YES it would returned `TX ` cause ajax is an asynchronous. Otherwise it must show the assigned value

Comment: Right - I follow.  So I did it both places.  I log it when the function first fires and it logs the default value of **TX**.  Inside the AJAX callback I log it again and it logs to the selected person's value of **MN**  But the selected value doesn't change from TX.

Comment: And this `$("AttState").val(selState);` should have `#` indicated for ID like following : `$("#AttState").val(selState);`, put this inside success callback again.

Comment: Well, I think I've stumbled on the issue and it appears to have something to do with the bootstrap-select **selectpicker** style I was applying to that selectbox.  When I take that attribute off my select box, it works as expected.  I've never seen a CSS class interfere with javascript in this way before.  I really appreciate your effort helping me out, but I don't think it's worth it if that's all the issue is.

Comment: Yeah, if you're using any plugin for styling of select like `select2`, input check box like `icheck`, then you should use their api to interact with. CSS class do interfere as jQuery used class or id to manipulate DOM element, and if you can see the source code of applied style, the DOM really changed and have some additional tag around it.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer as your last api comment prompted me to search the bootstrap-select api for preselecting and it was right there.  Thanks again.

Comment: No worries, and glad to hear that. You're welcome mate